# Javascript listindex Event Handling

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to fire up event handling based on the listindex of a DOM element. I can't quite figure why the code doesn't work as I'm running it in a bootstrap environment.

Javascript:

```
 window.onload = function(){
 function getEventTarget(e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 return e.target || e.srcElement; 
 }
 var ul = document.getElementById("aloga");
 ul.onclick = function(event) {
 var target = getEventTarget(event);
 var bman = getElementsByTagName("option")
 if (target.selectedIndex == "0") {
    window.alert("Hello Peter")
 } else if (target.selectedIndex == "1") {
    window.alert("Hello Paul")
 } else {
    window.alert("Hello Penn")
 }
 };
 }
```

Then here is the HTML code below:

```
 <select name="aloga" data-placeholder="Select your aloga" id="aloga"      class="form-control input-lg select2">
 <option value="1" data-code="A" selected > Peter </option>
 <option value="2" data-code="B"> Paul </option>
 <option value="3" data-code="C"> Penn </option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your javascript code with this.

```
document.getElementById("aloga").onchange = function(){
  var index = this.selectedIndex;
  var name = this.options[index].text;
  window.alert("Hello "+name);
}
```

jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ueyorfej/

Comment: Thanks checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change `getElementsByTagName("option")` to `document.getElementsByTagName("option")`

Answer (score 0):

**I agree with brk's comment but still if that doesn't work then i am pasting my working code for reference**

> ### Note: I have embedded your code in a fucntion attachEvents() also modified the
>
> var bman = getElementsByTagName("option") to
>      var bman = document.getElementsByTagName("option") as below

```
        <html>
        <script> 
         function attachEvents(){
         function getEventTarget(e) {
         e = e || window.event;
         return e.target || e.srcElement; 
         }
         var ul = document.getElementById("aloga");
         ul.onclick = function(event) {
         var target = getEventTarget(event);
         var bman = document.getElementsByTagName("option")
         if (target.selectedIndex == "0") {
            window.alert("Hello Peter")
         } else if (target.selectedIndex == "1") {
            window.alert("Hello Paul")
         } else {
            window.alert("Hello Penn")
         }
         };
         }
         </script>
        Then here is the HTML code below:
        <body onload="attachEvents()">
         <select name="aloga" data-placeholder="Select your aloga" id="aloga"      class="form-control input-lg select2">
         <option value="1" data-code="A" selected > Peter </option>
         <option value="2" data-code="B"> Paul </option>
         <option value="3" data-code="C"> Penn </option>
         </select>
         </body>
         </html>
```